# How can I append time pieces per value in a column?

Tags: python

I am trying to forecast the consumption rate of a series of different objects forward until they reach 0.

Say I have 10 models.  A B C D E F G H I J.

A should have the years 2019 through to 2100 appended to it. Copying the values in the rows over 81 times.

Then I want to basically say for 2020, what was the previous years forecasted inventory? I'll use that number from the previous row to calculate 2020's inventory then for 2021 I'll look back to 2020. Etc.

Currently I've only been able to do this by creating a column per year per metric which is not ideal.

I want to do this calculation so that I do not have to continuously add new columns for the following year. Rather I want to add in rows

```
build_plans = ['2019 build plan',
   '2020 build plan', '2021 build plan', '2022 build plan',
   '2023 build plan', '2024 build plan', '2025 build plan',
   '2026 build plan', '2027 build plan', '2028 build plan',
   '2029 build plan', '2030 build plan', '2031 build plan',
   '2032 build plan', '2033 build plan', '2034 build plan',
   '2035 build plan', '2036 build plan', '2037 build plan',
   '2038 build plan', '2039 build plan', '2040 build plan',
   '2041 build plan', '2042 build plan', '2043 build plan',
   '2044 build plan', '2045 build plan', '2046 build plan',
   '2047 build plan', '2048 build plan', '2049 build plan',
   '2050 build plan', '2051 build plan', '2052 build plan',
   '2053 build plan', '2054 build plan', '2055 build plan',
   '2056 build plan', '2057 build plan', '2058 build plan',
   '2059 build plan', '2060 build plan', '2061 build plan',
   '2062 build plan', '2063 build plan', '2064 build plan',
   '2065 build plan', '2066 build plan', '2067 build plan',
   '2068 build plan', '2069 build plan', '2070 build plan',
   '2071 build plan', '2072 build plan', '2073 build plan',
   '2074 build plan', '2075 build plan', '2076 build plan',
   '2077 build plan', '2078 build plan', '2079 build plan',
   '2080 build plan', '2081 build plan', '2082 build plan',
   '2083 build plan', '2084 build plan', '2085 build plan',
   '2086 build plan', '2087 build plan', '2088 build plan',
   '2089 build plan', '2090 build plan', '2091 build plan',
   '2092 build plan', '2093 build plan', '2094 build plan',
   '2095 build plan', '2096 build plan', '2097 build plan',
   '2098 build plan', '2099 build plan', '2100 build plan']





 i=0

 for x in build_plans:

    t = x[:5]
    y=0

    if i==0:
        LTB[f"{t} Install Base Forecasted "] = LTB["Install Base"] + LTB[x]
        LTB[f"{t} Components used in new builds"] =  LTB[x]
        LTB[f"{t} Components used in Z"] =  LTB[x] * LTB[Z Replacements']
        LTB[f"{t} Components used in B"] =  LTB[f"{t} Install Base Forecasted "]  * LTB['B Replacements']
        LTB[f"{t} Total Components Used "] = LTB[f"{t} Components used in new builds"] +LTB[f"{t} Components used in Warranty"]+ LTB[f"{t} Components used in B"]
        LTB[f"{t} Account for __ yield "] =  LTB[f"{t} Total Components Used "] /.99/.98
        LTB[f"{t} buffer 10%"] =  LTB[f"{t} Account for__ yield "] *1.1
        LTB[f"{t} Forecasted Inventory "] = LTB[f"{t} Install Base Forecasted "] -  LTB[f"{t} buffer 10%"]


    else: 
        z = build_plans[i-1]
        v= z[:5]

        LTB[f"{t} Install Base Forecasted "] = LTB[f"{v} Install Base Forecasted "] + LTB[x] -LTB[f"{v} Components used in B"]
        LTB[f"{t} Components used in new builds"] =  LTB[x]
        LTB[f"{t} Components used in Z"] =  LTB[x] * LTB[Z Replacements']
        LTB[f"{t} Components used in B"] =  LTB[f"{t} Install Base Forecasted "]  * LTB['B Replacements']
        LTB[f"{t} Total Components Used "] = LTB[f"{t} Components used in new builds"] +LTB[f"{t} Components used in Warranty"]+ LTB[f"{t} Components used in B"]
        LTB[f"{t} Account for __ yield "] =  LTB[f"{t} Total Components Used "] /.99/.98
        LTB[f"{t} buffer 10%"] =  LTB[f"{t} Account for__ yield "] *1.1
        LTB[f"{t} Forecasted Inventory "] = LTB[f"{t} Install Base Forecasted "] -  LTB[f"{t} buffer 10%"]

        LTB[f"{t} Install Base Forecasted "] = LTB.loc[LTB[f"{t} Install Base Forecasted "]<=0, f"{t} Install Base Forecasted "] =0
        LTB[f"{t} Forecasted Inventory "] = LTB.loc[LTB[f"{t} Forecasted Inventory "]<=0, f"{t} Forecasted Inventory "] =0
    i+=1

`
```

Rather than creating these columns I want a column for years that has values from 2019 to 2100 and a column for each output that corresponds to the current year

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, there are about 20 different models.

so for example: Model A would have a row per year  2019 to 2100. Model B would also have the same range.

Comment: You seem to have an indentation error in your code. And where is variable LTB declared? I am not familiar with your problem domain. But others might find it helpful if you provided some example of simple input and what your expected output would be. I can't tell from your description what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Thanks for the heads up. I tried to make the intent more clear.

Comment: @Nabonidus3 I cannot run your code. please add the definition of LTB as Ronald mentioned.

Comment: @Manuel I've managed to solve the issue. I posted the solution using a temporary database. The main issue I was experiencing was how to take a dataframe and add a range of years per row.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue using a temporary DF:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2], [2,1]]), columns = ["A", "B"])
year = pd.Series(range(2019,2100,1))
index = len(year)* len(df)
index
sd= pd.DataFrame(index = range(0, index+1,1))
i=0
for x in year:
    for z,y in df.iterrows():
        sd.loc[i,"Year"] =x
        sd.loc[i,"Value"] =df.loc[z,"A"]
        sd.loc[i,"Value2"] =df.loc[z,"B"]
        i+=1
```

Result:

```
    Year  Value     Value2
0   2019.0  1.0     2.0
1   2019.0  2.0     1.0
2   2020.0  1.0     2.0
3   2020.0  2.0     1.0
4   2021.0  1.0     2.0
5   2021.0  2.0     1.0
6   2022.0  1.0     2.0
7   2022.0  2.0     1.0
8   2023.0  1.0     2.0
9   2023.0  2.0     1.0
10  2024.0  1.0     2.0
...     ...     ...     ...


163 rows × 3 columns
```

This was the main issue I was trying to solve. How to take a dataframe and expand it based on a year range. This code appears to solve it.

For bringing in previous year values it would be something like this within the main body of the loop:

```
index = len(year)* len(df)
index
sd= pd.DataFrame(index = range(0, index+1,1))
i=0
for x in year:
    for z,y in df.iterrows():
        sd.loc[i,"Year"] =x
        if i!=0:
            sd.loc[i,"Value"] =sd.loc[i-1,"Value"] + df.loc[z,"A"]
        else:
            sd.loc[i,"Value"] =df.loc[z,"A"]
        sd.loc[i,"Value2"] =df.loc[z,"B"]
        i+=1


    Year    Value   Value2
0   2019.0  1.0     2.0
1   2019.0  3.0     1.0
2   2020.0  4.0     2.0
3   2020.0  6.0     1.0
4   2021.0  7.0     2.0
5   2021.0  9.0     1.0
6   2022.0  10.0    2.0
7   2022.0  12.0    1.0
8   2023.0  13.0    2.0
9   2023.0  15.0    1.0
```